# How To write special characters in settings.xml file

Tags: maven

Hi I am setting up my maven. In setting.xml file i need to setup my username and password. In password i have two special characters &* how can i write special characters in xml file.

Thanks and Regards,
Priyanka

Comment: I think your question is too generic. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution would be two fold-

- You would need to have a trigger on that table where the changes are made. There are APIs from the databases to help you listen to these events in your code. For example, H2 database provides a Java APIs.
- For seeing that change in the UI, without the user refreshing the page, you would need server push, WebSockets and CometD are the examples.

Comment: You can certainly combine ajax but ajax alone may not help in this case. Ajax is basically for non blocking calls, so you make a request but don't wait for the response, instead pass a callback to deal with the response. You certainly going to need server push in a good solution, client side polling is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution that might help - http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/